# BackboneJs: using partial fetch versus 1 collection through the whole lifespan of the application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, backbone.js

I'm a bit confused with the fetch on collections, 
the way i see it now, semantically fetch would go get all available models from the server
but sometimes you need only the top 5 or you want to show the items per 10 (paging for example)

example:

```
Movie = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "Id"
});

MovieList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Movie,
    url: "/api/movies"
});

$(function(){
    movies = new MovieList();
    movies.fetch(); // simplified example, i know best practice is not to fetch on document ready...
});
```

this show's a model called movie, in a movielist collection, calling `movies.fetch();` goes to the url beeing `/movies` which is build in asp.net mvc3 and - simplified for this example - basicly returns all movies in the database.

now, lets say I create a dashboard view that - among other things - is supposed to show the 10 most recent movies

do i need to go do a fetch again but somehow pass in i only want the top 10?
or, do i need to work with 1 collection of all movies through the whole lifetime of my application? and just query the collection instead?

if i would to the latter, and use 1 collection trough the entire app, how do i keep it up to date? other users might have added movies in the meantime, without going so far as using sockets for real time visualisation.

the more i think about it the more idea's i get where not the full collection is used, so either querying the server and getting only the necessary or getting it all once and querying the collection would be the actuall question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done this yet, but am considering it too. If keeping 1 collection I would probably set up a movies-changes service that returns command objects indicating new movies, modifications, and deletions. Long poll this service with a "since=<timestamp>" parameter to get the changes since the last time you checked, and use the response to update the collection. That should fire change events so views know to update.

Comment: thanks for this comment, i'm still in the process of building my app structure, when i get to this i will defenately give your solution a shot, i will accept as answer when and if i see it working :P